# Can Apple Help books handle links using a custom URL protocol?

Tags: macos, url

I'm writing a help book for a Mac application to be released in the Apple Mac App store.

When it preview the help book in Safari, links that use a custom URL protocol launch my app and pass it the URL. This is very useful for the help book, since the app lets you create documents using info encoded into a custom URL.

Once I build the help book into my app and read it using the help viewer, however, the links don't work any more.

It looks like the help viewer only supports the HTTP protocol. Has anybody else found a work-around for this? I really don't want to create HTTP links that route to a web server, and get redirected to a custom URL that ends up launching our app. That would be a bad user experience, and would mean using the help book required a live Internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run AppleScripts from help books (`x-help-script://...`), so you could easily create a generic URL launching mechanism this way (or a specific one to target your app).  More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-TPXREF110).

Comment: Ugh. What a nasty thing to have to resort to. I guess it would work, though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Really doesn't seem that bad to me given some of the things I've had to resort to, but :-)

Comment: As of 10.14 this is not working anymore and the link doesn't contain any reference to it, probably because of CVE-2017-2316.

Comment: Agree this was probably removed for security reasons, but I think you have the wrong CVE.